# Is there a better alternative to extending the SlingPostServlet?

Tags: java, sling

In a Sling application, I want to ensure that nodes created with a particular `sling:resourceType` always have a child node created with specific properties. What way to achieve this conforms to best practice?

1. Extending the `SlingPostServlet` class and adding functionality to add the child node within the `doPost()` method. This would appear a good fit since one could, on first glance, link the servlet to the specific resource type, and call `super.doPost()` to make use of the default `SlingPostServlet` processing. However, when installing the bundle, `org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl` cannot be resolved ([a similar problem was encountered by another user](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2329392)), which prevents the bundle from running at all.
2. Creating a `SlingPostProcessor` and adding functionality within the `process()` method. This seems less desirable since it is not tied to one particular resource type.
3. Using [Sling Eventing](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/apache-sling-eventing-and-job-handling.html).

I wanted to avoid extending `SlingAllMethodsServlet`, since it would be useful to maintain access to all the default functionality in `SlingPostServlet`. However, is it even possible to extend `SlingPostServlet`, rather than `SlingAllMethodsServlet`?

Comment: My gut tells me that `SlingPostProcessor` is a good option. I don't think that filtering every incoming request "by hand" (looking if the resource type fits) is that expensive. But I am looking forward to what others have to say. The thing is: Usually, you should not do a lot of the processing in the `SlingPostProcessor` or `SlingPostServlet` anyway. The business logic should be in a service. So if no better answer comes up I would just start with the `SlingPostProcessor` and see if that creates any problems. If that does not work you do not need to change a lot. Avoid pre-mature optimization.

Comment: have you looked at the [content import option available with SlingPostServlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#importing-content-structures)?, seems like a perfect solution for your use case.

Comment: @Jens After thinking about the issue, I also was inclined to go with `SlingPostProcessor`, which was relatively simple to set up. However, following @santiagozky's answer, I opted for Resource observation, which has the advantage that it should check for changes other than those effected though `SlingPostServlet`. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @awd I looked at that documentation, but don't immediately see how it would fit my scenario of needing to set up a child node.

Comment: the import option allows you to specify a json as node structure, you can specify child node type in json, e.g. following code will create a node sample with a child node childOne - `curl -u admin:admin -F":operation=import" -F":contentType=json" -F":name=sample" -F':content={ "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured", "propOne" : "propOneValue", "childOne" : { "childPropOne" : true, "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured"} }' http://localhost:4502/tmp/content/test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple solution to bind that behavior to a single resource Type. you will need to check the new resource and apply your changes if needed.
I think the two best options are the SlingPostProcessor you mentioned and [Resource observation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/resources.html#resource-observation).

Resource observation allows you to 'listen'  for changes in resources and perform any operation you might see fit.

The implementation is fairly straight forward as well. Create a new OSGi service that implements the ResourceChangeListener interface and add some properties to filter what kind of changes you are interested in. This is similar to using JCR events and a job, but much more straight forward.

The benefit of this is that this is independent on any post request. the drawback is that you need to use a new session to perform your changes. (You can use `ResourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver`)

For example.

```
@Component(property = {
    ResourceChangeListener.CHANGES + "=ADDED",
    ResourceChangeListener.PATHS + "=glob:/content/*",
})
public class ResourceObserver implements ResourceChangeListener {

  @Override
  public void onChange(@Nonnull List<ResourceChange> changes) {
      //go through the list of changes and do what you need to do.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the option I've gone for. I had some issues setting up the service user (apparently it needs the permission `rep:write`and not just `jcr:write`), but apart from that, it seems to be working well enough.